# How to use 2 factor authentication for login in umbraco backoffice

Tags: umbraco

i am trying to find something to use 2 factor authentication while a user logs in umbraco backoffice.

Tried using this link https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/47828-2-factor-authentication

But still nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a 2-factor authentication package available that will work with the Google Authenticator app.

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/umbraco-2fa/
https://github.com/Offroadcode/Umbraco-2FA

Note that it only runs on v7.6+.

Comment: Is there anything for Umbraco version 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco now supports External Authentication (Google OAuth, Twitter, Microsoft, AzureAD, etc.) through OWIN and the UmbracoIdentityExtensions package:

https://github.com/umbraco/UmbracoIdentityExtensions

However, I don't think 2-factor Authentication is implemented yet.